# Access arbitrary keys in blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to access keys of objects that are usually disallowed by Meteor, such as keys starting with a number, but especially GUIDs.

What I tried initally:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{property.62f53e2e-e4d3-4ff1-b451-2325a6bfbfd0}} />
```

... but that throws `Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, or null`.

Next I tried JavaScript-style:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{property['62f53e2e-e4d3-4ff1-b451-2325a6bfbfd0']}} />
```

... this throws a `Exception from Tracker recompute function: Can't call non-function: [object Object]`

Is there any clean way to access these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you pass the object via template data, what about a helper function in a .js file?

```
Template.someTemplate.helpers({
    property : function()
    {
        return this.property['62f53e2e-e4d3-4ff1-b451-2325a6bfbfd0'];
    }
});
```

(Edit: then you would simply put `{{property}}` in your template)

Comment: I thought about this approach too, I was just hoping that there might be a native solution without "workarounds". I'll accept your answer if no native solution appears.

Comment: Thing is, the code in `{{ here }}` is supposed to be a function, or a direct access to the template data... I'm checking the [Spacebards doc](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md) to see if it could be done with a `#with`

Comment: Nop, no luck. Either escape your key name (`property._62f53`) or use a helper. Sorry =/

Comment: Well, the issue is that _each block_ of the GUID would need to be escaped for some reason, the parser breaks after each `-` (e.g. `abcdef-2222` will break at the `2`.)
I'll try to file a bug and see if they will include a proper way to escape properties, but I'll have to go with the helper for now.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kyll already described, only a helper can really do this *for now* (just filed a bug/feature request [on GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3062)).

If you (for some reason) want a common helper, you can also use this:

```
objectProperty: (object, propertyName) -> object[propertyName]
```

...and put this into your template:

```
{{objectProperty property '62f53e2e-e4d3-4ff1-b451-2325a6bfbfd0'}}
```